# How can I render data vertically in React Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-flatlist

there are multiple `variations` for one product and I want to render them all in FlatList or SectionList:

JSON:

```
[
    {
       ...
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "title": "chicken burger 2",
        "sort": 2,
        "img": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/categories/unnamed_tyEgUqN.jpg",
        "price": 2.0,
        "category": {
            "id": 1,
            "title": "sandwiches",
            "img": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/categories/original_D3hTuRE.jpg"
        },
        "description": "chicken burger chicken burger chicken burger chicken burger chicken burger chicken burger chicken burger chicken burger chicken burger chick",
        "variations": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "variation_category": {
                    "id": 1,
                    "title": "add ons",
                    "is_optional": true,
                    "is_selectable": false
                },
                "item": "extra cheese",
                "price": 0.1
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "variation_category": {
                    "id": 1,
                    "title": "add ons",
                    "is_optional": true,
                    "is_selectable": false
                },
                "item": "double chicken",
                "price": 0.6
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I got all variations for the product by this code:

```
function ProductDetailScreen(props) {
    //api
  const [productsData, setProductsData] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    loadProductsData();
  }, []);

  const loadProductsData = async () => {
    const response = await productsApi.getProducts();
    setProductsData(response.data);
  };
  const productId = props.route.params.productId;
  const thisProduct = productsData.filter((prod) => prod.id === productId);
const variations = thisProduct.map((product) =>
    product.variations.map((variation) => variation.item)
  );
return (
    
    ...
      {variations &&
    variations.map((variation, index) => (
      <View key={index}>
        <Addons item={variation} />
      </View>
    ))}
...
)
```

but they look like this on the mobile screen => :
[horizontally](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m1CaM.jpg)

My question is how can I render them vertically to look like this:

```
extra cheese 0.100
double chicken 0.600
```

`Edit:`
Addons component as requested:

```
import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";
// Config
import colors from "../config/colors";
import MyText from "../config/MyText";
// Icons
import { Feather } from "@expo/vector-icons";

function Addons(props) {
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={props.onPress} style={styles.card}>
        <Feather name="check-square" size={24} color="black" />
        <MyText padding={10}>{props.item}</MyText>
        <MyText padding={10}>{props.price}</MyText>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  card: {
    height: 50,
    width: 300,
    backgroundColor: colors.white,
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    borderBottomColor: colors.disabled,
    justifyContent: "space-between",
    alignItems: "center",
    flexDirection: "column",
    alignSelf: "center"
  },
});

export default Addons;
```

Thank you in advance,

Comment: wouldnt a `flex-direction:column` help?

Comment: Yes, It wouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

Main View inside of your Addons component should have the style below

```
container: 
{ 
  flex: 1, 
  alignItems: "center", 
  justifyContent: "center", 
  flexDirection: "column", 
},
```

Edit: The code block below, you can get the rows vertically

```
 <View style={{ flex:1, flexDirection:"column" }}>
   variations.map((variation, index) => (
   <View key={index} style={{ flex:1 }}>
     <Addons item={variation} />
   </View>
</View>
```

This should solve your problem

Comment: Can you provide code of Addons so it can be more clear? Please add in the main post as an edit

Comment: Sure. It's added

Comment: please have a look in the edit part of my answer.